# Dynamical getters always return undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I trying to learn Nest.js and i got problem which i cant fix.
I got IndexDto class

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsObject()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(transformJson)
  private filter?: T;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(transformJson)
  private range?: T;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(transformJson)
  private sort?: T;

  get rangeBegin(): number {
    return this.range ? this.range[0] : 0;
  }

  get skip(): number {
    return this.rangeBegin;
  }

  get rangeEnd(): number {
    return this.range ? this.range[1] : 19;
  }

  get take(): number {
    return this.rangeBegin - this.rangeEnd + 1;
  }

  get sortField(): string {
    return this.sort ? this.sort[0] : 'id';
  }

  get sortValue(): Sort {
    return (this.sort ? this.sort[1] : 'DESC') as Sort;
  }

  get filterValue(): Filter {
    return this.filter ? this.filter : {};
```

and im using it abstract service class on function index

```
  async index(indexDto: IndexDto): Promise<[Entity[], number]> {
    return this.filterByFieldsOfEntity(indexDto.filterValue)
      .then((where) =>
        this.repository
          .createQueryBuilder(this.tableName)
          .where(where)
          .skip(indexDto.skip)
          .take(indexDto.take)
          .orderBy(
            `${this.tableName}.${indexDto.sortField}`,
            indexDto.sortValue,
          ),
      )
      .then((builder) => this.filterSpecific(builder, indexDto.filterValue))
      .then((builder) => builder.getManyAndCount());
  }
```

So what is a problem:
Any of getters always return undefined,
but if i call `indexDto.filter` for example its return correct value from request
what im doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you ensure the DTO instance is created? Are you using the `ValidationPipe`, and if so do you have `transform: true`?